# StripeCardError: Cannot charge a customer that has no active card. Trying to make a payment using Stripe

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

So I am trying to make a test payment using Stripe, React and Nodejs.

on the front-end I am using `createPaymentMethod()` and sending a post request with valid user information related to products, how many items, user and address info. Like so:

```
const purchase = {
          ...paymentMethod,
          address: {
            line1: `${user.address.number} ${user.address.street}`,
            postal_code: user.address.zipcode,
            city: user.address.city,
            state: user.address.state,
            country: 'Brazil'
          },
          customer: {
            email: user.email,
            name: user.name,
          },
          product,
          quantity,
        }

        let data = await fetch('http://localhost:3002/checkout', {
          method: 'post',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(purchase),
        })
```

So far so good...

On the backend I am retrieving this information and using `stripe.customers.create()` when the user hasn't been created yet

```
      const customerPurchase = await stripe.customers.create({
        email: customer.email,
        name: customer.name,
        address,
        payment_method: payment_method_id //response from paymentMethod on the front end
      })
```

And finally, to create the charge I use `charges.create()` method:

```
const idempotencyKey = uuid()

    return stripe.charges.create({
      amount: product.price * quantity * 100,
      currency: 'brl',
      customer: customerStripeId,
      receipt_email: customer.email,
      description: `Congratulations! You just purchased the item: ${product.name}!`,
      shipping: {
        address: {
          line1: address.line1,
          city: 'Manaus',
          country: 'Brazil',
          postal_code: address.zipcode,
        }
      }

    },{
      idempotencyKey
    })
```

However I am getting this error: `StripeCardError: Cannot charge a customer that has no active card`.

I figured it might have something to do with some `source` property that had to be passed like this: `source: req.body.stripeToken`. However, I have no clue where to get this stripeToken, tried everything but hasn't found anything yet.

Can someone help me please? I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Payment Methods directly with Charges, you should use the newer Payment Intents API instead following [this guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?integration=elements), which has the added benefit of supporting [Strong Customer Authentication](https://stripe.com/docs/strong-customer-authentication).

To create a payment for a Customer *after* already attaching a payment method, you can retrieve the payment methods for that customer and then create a payment:

```
const paymentMethods = await stripe.paymentMethods.list({
  customer: '{{CUSTOMER_ID}}',
  type: 'card',
});
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: 1099,
    currency: 'usd',
    customer: '{{CUSTOMER_ID}}',
    payment_method: '{{PAYMENT_METHOD_ID}}',
  });
```

and then [confirm that payment on the client side](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#web-submit-payment):

```
stripe.confirmCardPayment(intent.client_secret)
```

If you're previously had the Customer authenticate and [prepared that card for later use](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment), you can [confirm on the server side when charging later](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment#web-create-payment-intent-off-session):

```
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: 1099,
    currency: 'usd',
    customer: '{{CUSTOMER_ID}}',
    payment_method: '{{PAYMENT_METHOD_ID}}',
    off_session: true,
    confirm: true,
  });
```